# Mutate function: Sort a character string and remove duplicate characters

Tags: r, stringr, dplyr

I know that this must be so easy that there are already functions available, perhaps in stringr, to do this ... but I am not having any luck finding an answer.

I have a dataframe with one column:

```
> df1 <- tibble(col1=c("abac", "aacabb"))
> df1
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  col1  
  <chr> 
1 abac  
2 aacabb
```

and I want to create two new columns so that I end up with:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  col1   col2   col3 
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1 abac   aabc   abc  
2 aacabb aaabbc abc
```

where col2 has the characters in order and col3 has the duplicate characters removed. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. I have not seen the "~" or ".x" used before ... obviously I need to do some reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
lst1 <- lapply(strsplit(df1$col1, ""), sort)
df1$col2 <-  sapply(lst1, function(x) paste(x, collapse=""))
df1$col3 <- sapply(lst1, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=""))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(tmp = str_extract_all(col1, "."), 
          col2 = map_chr(tmp, ~ str_c(sort(.x), collapse="")),
          col3 = map_chr(tmp, ~ str_c(unique(sort(.x)), collapse="")), 
          tmp = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  col1   col2   col3 
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1 abac   aabc   abc  
#2 aacabb aaabbc abc
```

Answer (score 0):

a similar option using `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1=c("abac", "aacabb"))

df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = map_chr(str_split(col1, ""), ~str_c(str_sort(.x), collapse = "")),
         col3 = map_chr(str_split(col1, ""), ~str_c(str_sort(unique(.x)), collapse = "")))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   col1   col2   col3 
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 abac   aabc   abc  
#> 2 aacabb aaabbc abc
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>